# Unable to send more than the first user data

Tags: android

I am making an admin page. I want to edit the user data if there is anything wrong.
Below is my table where admin can click "Edit" to edit the information.
I manage to get the data from this activity to second activity, but the data will only follow the first row.
When I click Edit for second row (BI14110391, Totalmarks:3), the data still remains to the first row data(BI14110104, Total Marks=8)

[image]

My code:

```
    public class assessment_table_edit extends AppCompatActivity {
        Toolbar toolbar;
        String data = "";
        TableLayout tlAssessment;
        TableRow tr;
        TextView stuID,totalmarks,marks,edit;
        ArrayList<Assessment_Information> users;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_assessment_table_edit);
            toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Percentage of the Marks");
            tlAssessment=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlAssessment_Edit);


            final Assessment_Information_GetData getdb=new Assessment_Information_GetData();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    data =getdb.getDataFromDB();
                    System.out.println(data);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            users=parseJSON(data);
                            addData(users);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();

        }

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.assessment_id:
 //Problem is here   
                        Intent iChange=new Intent(assessment_table_edit.this,assessment_edit_data.class);
                        Bundle b=new Bundle();
                        b.putString("stuID", users.get(0).getStuID());
                        b.putString("totalmarks",users.get(1).getTotalmarks());
                        iChange.putExtras(b);
                        // iChange.putExtra("stuID",user.getStuID());
                        startActivity(iChange);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: why you get always first and second records (users.get(0), users.get(1))

Comment: That is the reason I asking here for help.

Answer (score 0):

The code below refers to wrong position when fetching data from row.

```
Intent iChange=new Intent(assessment_table_edit.this,assessment_edit_data.class);
                    Bundle b=new Bundle();
                    b.putString("stuID", **users.get(0).getStuID()**);
                    b.putString("totalmarks",**users.get(1).getTotalmarks()**);
                    iChange.putExtras(b);
                    // iChange.putExtra("stuID",user.getStuID());
                    startActivity(iChange);
```

Please use proper position value.

Comment: What should i use ?

Comment: If you are Editing first row, please send 0 position and second row then 1 position.
Depending on your row number, send the position as row number to fetch data from list.